# Office 365 Sharepoint Transfer Storage From OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, onedrive-for-business

We have bought Office 365 Business Premium and it seems that we only have 30GB Sharepoint space. Is it possible to use space from the 1TB OneDrive or to upgrade the space?

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive storage is different from SharePoint Online storage. You can purchase additional SharePoint Online storage from [Office 365 Admin Portal](http://portal.microsoftonline.com/Commerce/Manage.aspx), Subscription Details.

[Source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2012/07/11/how-to-add-extra-storage-to-sharepoint-online.aspx)

Comment: I heard a rumor that there is a New Policy where you choose where to allocate space per tenant. Is this true or do you say just buy more space.